# How to prevent refreshing the page on clicking the buttton with jquery, but allowing the flask view function delete the from database?

Tags: html, jquery, flask

I want the view function named post_to_delete in python will delete the data but I want to prevent the div named "formNewPost" from being displayed. I want the div named 'tablePosts' to be refreshed.the view functions are in flask.Thank You.
How to prevent refreshing the page on clicking the buttton with jquery, but allowing the flask view function delete the from database?

### 'HTML'

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row align-items-start">
                <div class="col-lg-8 " id="formNewPost">
                        <form action="{{url_for('posts.post_add')}}" method="POST" >
                            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="">
                          <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2">
                              <label for="inputTitle">Post Title</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" name="post_title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2">
                              <label for="inputPostAuthor">Author Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPostAuthor" name="post_author">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                           <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <label for="inputPost">Post Date</label>
                              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputPost" name="post_date">
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputOwnerId">Post Owner Id</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputOwnerId" name="post_owner_id" >
                              </div>
                               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                   <label for="inputImageName" >browse path</label>
                                  <div class="custom-file">
                                     <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputImageName" name="image_name" >
                                     <label class="custom-file-label" for ="inputImageName" >Choose file...</label>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-row" >
                               <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                  <label for="postDetails">Post Details</label>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" id="postDetails" rows="5" name="post_details"></textarea>
                               </div>
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                  <label for="postExtraDetails">Post Extra Details</label>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" id="postExtraDetails" rows="2" name="post_extra_details"></textarea>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">post</button>
                        </form>
                </div>


<!-- div represents a table that allows to delete posts -->
                <div id="tablePosts" class="col-lg-8" style="display:none">
                    <div class ="table-responsive" >
                       <table class ="table" >
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th scope = "col" > Post Id </th>
                                 <th scope = "col" > Post title </th>
                                 <th scope = "col" > Post By </th>
                                 <th scope = "col" > Post Date </th>
                                 <th scope = "col" >  </th>
                              </tr >
                          </thead >
                          <tbody >
                           {% for post in all_posts %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope = "row" > {{post.postId}} </th>
                                <td >  {{post.postTitle}} </td>
                                <td > {{post.postBy}} </td>
                                <td >{{post.postDate}} </td>
                                <td ><a href="{{url_for('posts.post_to_delete',post_id=post.postId)}}"> <button id="delete_post"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " >dell</button></a></td>
                            </tr >
                           {% endfor %}
                        </tbody >
                       </table >
                     </div >
                </div>




            <div class="col-lg-4 pr-0">
              <img class="img-fluid pr-0 pl-4 pt-3 pb-3" src = "{{ url_for('static', filename='css/reading pink.jpg')}}" >
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row" >
            <div class ="col-lg-12">
               <a href="">
              <button id="delete"  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">delete post</button>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}   


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'JavaScript'
$('#delete').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('this button was clicked');
        $('#formNewPost').hide();
        $('#tablePosts .col-lg-8').css("display:inline"); 
        $('#tablePosts').show(); 
        $('#formNewPost').css("display:none"); 
       
     
  })


  $('#tablePosts tr td a').on('click',function(event){
      alert("in this");
      var aLi = $('#tablePosts tr td a');
      console.log(aLi);
      console.log(aLi.length);
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      alert(url);
     
       

      
      
      
        
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function in python for delete the entry from the database and allow only delete method.

```
@app.route('/delete-this', methods=['DELETE'])
def dalete_entry():
    data = request.form
    cur.execute("DELETE from table_name WHERE id = {}".format(data['id']))
    con.commit()
    return jsonify({'status': 'Deleted Successfully', 'deleted_id': data['id']})
```

Then add this in your script

```
$('#delete').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // data['id'] = take id or some reference from your html page 
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{url_for('dalete_entry')}}',
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: data
        success: function(result) {
            // Do something 
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you. I am working with SQLAlchemy so I'll query,than return jsonify.